# How to submit a select menu without a submit button in a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a code that submits a form when an option in a select box is clicked, but my problem is when I put it inside a loop, it doesn't work. Can you help me with it?

Here's the code:

```
<?php 
  $y1=5;
  for($x1=1; $x1<=$y1; $x1++){
?>
    <form name="myform[]" action="test.php" id ="myform" method="post">
      <select id="sel_id" name="sel_name[]"  onchange="submitform();">
      <?php 
        $y=5;
        for($x=1; $x<=$y; $x++){
      ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $x;?>"><?php echo $x;?></option>
      <?php
        }
      ?> 
      </select>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function submitform()
      {
        document.myform.submit();
      }
    </script>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Now, I want every value of it be printed:

```
<?php
  echo $_POST['sel_name'];
?>
```

Comment: Will you mind sharing parsed `markup` /

Comment: parsed markup? whats that? sorry im still a student

Comment: Markup which is formed after `php` script is executed..Developers tools will help..

Comment: every time you change option it will submit form. so then whats the use of other option box. i think you need to put a submit button after selecting all the option then you click to send the data to test.php page

Comment: nothing, thats just it, if you the plug in or the script? i didnt use any. it worls if i remove the first loop

Comment: <form name="myform[]" - the form declaration should not have a name it serves no real purpose. If you need to reference the form in javascript use id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using multiple form with same `id="myform"`. this should be unique for every form.

**Example:**

```
<?php 
$y1=5;
For($x1=1; $x1<=$y1; $x1++){
?>
<form name="myform[]" action="test.php" id ="myform_<?=$x1?>" method="post">
<select id="sel_id" name="sel_name[]"  onchange="submitform(<?=$x1?>);">
<?php 
$y=5;
For($x=1; $x<=$y; $x++){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $x;?>"><?php echo $x;?></option>
<?php
}
?> 
</select>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Your Java Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(id)
{
    document.getElementById("myform_"+id).submit();
}
</script>
```

**Your test.php:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sel_name']))
    print_r($_POST['sel_name']);
?>
```

I am using different form ids as `myform_<?=$x1?>` and also using this id into `submitform()` function.

As per @Mr.Engineer, no need to use java script function `submitform()` inside the `for()` when you are using the unique IDs for form submission.

Comment: Do you still need your js function in loop?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this inside your function `submitform()` :

```
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
```

**EDIT : I didnt notice your for loop**

You are using form in for loop, so you need separate id for each form.

So try this :

```
<?php 
$y1=5;
for($x1=1; $x1<=$y1; $x1++){
?>
<form name="myform[]" action="test.php" id ="myform<?php echo $x1;?>" method="post">
<select id="sel_id<?php echo $x1;?>" name="sel_name[]"  onchange="submitform(<?php echo $x1;?>);">
<?php 
$y=5;
for($x=1; $x<=$y; $x++){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $x;?>"><?php echo $x;?></option>
<?php
}
?> 
</select>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

And outside of your for loop write your JS function :

```
function submitform(id)
{
document.getElementById("myform"+id).submit();
}
```

Comment: @RayonDabre is it helpful now?

Comment: I'm just answering the question. Formatting of code should be done by OP.I'm saying this is the one way.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for submit form using selectbox.

```
<select id="sel_id" name="sel_name[]" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this may be it's help for you

```
$(field).closest("form").submit();
```

For example, to handle the onchange event, you would have this:

```
$(select your fields here).change(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: try to this one onchange="this.form.submit()" 

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/javascript/